# Deck of Cards taking dynamic input

Tags: java, arrays

Deck of Cards containing 13 characters from 1-13 where the values shown on the card represent the following numerical values:

```
'A' - 1
'2' - 2
'3' - 3
'4' - 4
'5' - 5
'6' - 6
'7' - 7
'8' - 8
'9' - 9
'T' - 10
'J' - 11
'Q' - 12
'K' - 13
```

The program should remove all the instances of 'K' card and any two consecutive numbers that sum up to 13.

I have written a program to remove instances of 'K' and numbers that sum up to 13 but I am not able figure out how to provide input of cards from user (using scanner class). I know scanner class takes the input but how do I compare with the existing array with dynamic input. Please help

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.*;

public class CircleGame
{
    static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    static int[] deckArray = {'A',2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,'T','J','Q','K'};

    public int cardsLeft(int[] deck, int sum)
    {           
        for(int i=0;i<deck.length;i++)
        {
            //char c = deck.charAt(i);

             if(deckArray[i] == 'A')
                deckArray[i] =   1;
             if(deckArray[i] == 'T')
                deckArray[i] =  10;
             if(deckArray[i] == 'J')
                deckArray[i] =  11;
             if(deckArray[i] == 'Q')
                deckArray[i] =  12;
             if(deckArray[i] == 'K')
                deckArray[i] =  -1;

             for(int j=0;j<deckArray.length;j++){
                 for(int k=j+1;k<deckArray.length;k++){
                     if(deckArray[j]+deckArray[k] == sum){
                         deckArray[j] = -1;
                         deckArray[k] = -1;
                     }
                 }
             }
        }
        int count = 0;
        for(int aDeckArray:deckArray)
        {
            if (aDeckArray != -1) {
                count++;
            }
        }
            return count;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        CircleGame c = new CircleGame();
        c.cardsLeft(deckArray,13);
    }       

}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you well, you want to let the user provide a deck.

The naive approach would be to do so :

```
   Scanner sc = new Scanner(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

// building of a list containing all possible cards. This way, you have a link between the symbol and the number
List<String> table = new ArrayList<String>();
table.add("A");
for (int i = 2; i <= 9; i++) {
  table.add(String.valueOf(i));
}
table.add("T");
table.add("J");
table.add("Q");
table.add("K");

int[] deck = new int[13];

for (int i = 0; i < 13; i++) {
  String input = sc.nextLine();
  // if the given symbol is invalid, try again
  if (!table.contains(input)) {
    System.out.println("Invalid card");
    i--;
  } else {
    deck[i] = table.indexOf(input); // if "A"-> 1, if "4"-> 4, ...
  }
}

// your internal logic to check if it is valid

for (int i = 0; i < l; i++) {
  if (deck[i] != -1) {
    System.out.println(String.valueOf(deck[i]));
  }
}
```

Comment: any idea how do I print unremoved cards of the deck ?

Comment: Appreciate your quick reply, but as an example, I am posting sample required output:  `If the user enters "KKKKKAQT23"
Returns: 1
The K cards are removed, leaving AQT23. AQ are then removed because they add up to 13, leaving T23. Since the deck wraps around and T and 3 add up to 13, they are also removed, just leaving the 2.`

Comment: @KiritiKomaragiri I see. In that case, you should print an output each time a card is removed using `System.out.println`. Would that be better ?

Comment: When I enter the dynamic data as 123456789TJQK, It is storing the data into deck[i] array as 49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,84,74,81,75. Then summ==13 will always be false. The characters of deck should be a character from the set {'2'-'9','A','T','J','Q','K'}.

Comment: @KiritiKomaragiri Indeed, I was a bit quick to write the code :) I'll correct it right away.

Comment: @KiritiKomaragiri sorry for the delay, I got caught somewhere else :) I generalized the code a little bit, please tell me if something isn't clear enough

Comment: Sorry for delayed response. Thanks a lot for your help. There are still some minor tweaks I will keep you posted